# Print UserData for specific key when a marker is tapped

Tags: swift, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

I've added a marker

```
var marker:  GMSMarker?
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.890106, longitude: -77.007362)
marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
var data = Dictionary<String, Any>()
data["type"] = "Mark1" as String
marker?.userData = data
marker?.map = self.map
```

Now in `func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {` I want to fetch the `["type"] value and for that when I do:

```
    if marker.userData["type"] == "Mark1" {
        print("It's Marker type 1")
    }
```

I get error:

> Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts

I've search stack overflow with this error above that solution is not related to my problem as it's not related to places.

**UPDATE**
If I simply print: `print(marker.userData!)` I get:

```
{
    type = Mark1;
}
```

But I'm not able to read type in If condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
   func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {


    guard let data = marker.userData as? [String:Any] else{return false}
    guard let type = data["type"] as? String else{return false}
    if type == "Mark1"  {
        print("It's Marker type 1")
    }
    return true
}
```